# reverse scroll to two ids parallel effect

Tags: jquery, html, jquery-ui

I am trying to recreate the reverse scroll effect like the link below where I am using jquery 1.9.1 version to create the scroll effect.

What i want to achieve is when ever scroll happens it automatically adjusts to next divs as in the sequence, unlike my code it only scrolls down a little...

[link](https://nationallgbtmuseum.org/)

I am using the html as below

```
   <div class="panelCon"> 
    <div id="pane-5" class="panel" style="">
        <h1>5</h1>
    </div>
    <div id="pane-4"class="panel">
        <h1>4</h1>
    </div>
    <div id="pane-3"class="panel">
        <h1>3</h1>
    </div>
    <div id="pane-2" class="panel">
        <h1>2</h1>
    </div>
    <div id="pane-1" class="panel">
        <h1>1</h1>
    </div>
    </div>

    <div class="panelCont"> 
     <div  class="panela">
        <h1>1</h1>
    </div>
     <div id="pane-2" class="panela">
        <h1>2</h1>
    </div>
     <div id="pane-3"class="panela">
        <h1>3</h1>
    </div>
     <div id="pane-4"class="panela">
        <h1>4</h1>
    </div>
    <div id="pane-5" class="panela">
        <h1>5</h1>
    </div>
   </div>
```

css:

```
body {
    margin: 0;
    padding: 0;
}
.panelCon{
    position: fixed;
    bottom: 0;
    left:0;
    width: 49%;
    float:left;
}
.panel {
    width: 100%;
}

.panela {
    width: 100%;
    height:600px;
    padding:20px;
}


.panel h1 {
    width: 100px;
    position: relative;
    display: block;
    margin: 0 auto;
    text-align: center;
    top: 50%;
}
#pane-1 {
   background:url('about.jpg');
   background-size:100% 100%;
}
#pane-2 {
    background-color: red;
}
#pane-3 {
    background-color: white;
}
#pane-4 {
    background-color: pink;
}
#pane-5 {
    background-color: yellow;
}


.panelCont{
    position:relative;
    bottom: 0;
    left:0;
    width: 51%;
    height:100%;
    float:left;
    font-size:99px;
    float:right;
    background-color:#333;
}
```

jquery 1.9.1

```
var winHeight = $(window).innerHeight();
$(document).ready(function () {
    $(".panel").height(winHeight);
    $("body").height(winHeight*$(".panel").length);
});

window.addEventListener('resize', function (event) {
    $(".panel").height($(window).innerHeight());
});
$(window).on('scroll',function(){
    $(".panelCon").css('bottom',$(window).scrollTop()*-1);
});
```

[my jsfiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/mukhesha/jmdzb5m3/)

Comment: What do you mean with "automatically adjusts to next divs as in the sequence" ?

Comment: check the url on scroll should be restricted in a way to take to second div on right and left same time and then to third and fourth.. as same while going back............... thanks for your time..................